# Numbers to base $i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Does it make sense to think of numbers to base $i$, i.e. $\sqrt{-1}$?
For conventional bases e.g. $N = 2, 8, 10, 16$ etc., we talk of using digits from $0$ through the base $N-1$ in the numeric representation. What digits would be permitted for base $i$?
What about other unconventional bases like $\pi$? $e$? Irrational numbers?

Just need a "frame of reference" to think through these things logically. Would appreciate pointers to papers or websites. I am not a Math PhD, just a hobbyist, so please keep explanations simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as base $i$ goes, see Donald Knuth's Quarter-Imaginary System: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base. It's pretty cool, and I think almost all complex numbers can be expressed uniquely (some may have two expressions). You could have base e or base pi, but they don't have much practical use imo (not just for scientific application, but in a pure mathematical sense, it would also have like no use). For something like base $\sqrt{2}$, it would alternate between just being binary and being a weird root 2 thing, which is interesting but again, not really practical.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the powers of $i$ don't grow because $i^4=1$.  Negative integers work fine for bases.  If you work in base $-2$ the position values are $1,-2,4,-8,16\ldots$.  You can represent all positive and negative integers with just $0$ and $1$.  $9_{10}=16-8+1=11001_{-2}$.  With a bit of work you can find algorithms for normal arithmetic.  Irrational bases can be made to work using digits up to the largest natural less than the base.  Base $\pi$ would use $0,1,2,3$.  You don't get a unique representation for some numbers and integers have infinite decimals.  That makes it such a mess that I haven't seen anyone find a use for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, it does *make sense* to think of numbers base $i$. If we have a string of digits $d_z$ for integers $z$, then this corresponds to $\sum_zd_zi^z$. However, unlike with normal number bases, there's no clear choice of what your set of digits should be (unlike $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ for decimal), and if they have to be integers, then we can only produce numbers called Gaussian integers; those of the form $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ both integers. Furthermore, unlike with normal bases, this only works if only finitely many of the $d_i$ are zero. Otherwise we get something like the number $1.111111...$ representing
$$1\times i^0+1\times i^1+1\times i^2+1\times i^3+1\times i^4...=1\times1+1\times i+1\times-1+1\times-i=1+i-1-i...$$
which doesn't make converge (once you define convergence for sequences of complex numbers). Furthermore, we have $100000000=10000=1$, since $i^8=i^4=i^0=1$. Of course $0.9999...=1$ in base ten but at least with normal bases we only have non-unique expansions for a subset of rational numbers, each of these only has two expansions, and one of them has terminating expansion and the other doesn't.